# Am I going crazy with the Perl string comparison operator? Debug log included

Tags: string, perl, comparison

I must be missing something about variable assignment or string comparison. I have a script that's going through a tab-separated file.  Unless one particular value in a row is "P", I want to skip to the next line.  The code looks like:

```
1 print "Processing inst_report file...\n";
2 foreach(@inst_report_file){
3    @line=split(/\t/);
4    ($line[13] ne "P") && next;
5    $inst_report{$line[1]}++;
6 }
```

For some reason, the script would never get to Line 5 even though there were clearly lines with "P" in it.

So debug time!

```
# Continuing to the breakpoint.
DB<13> c
main::(count.pl:27):        ($line[13] ne "P") && next;

# Proving that this particular array element is indeed "P" with no leading or trailing characters.
DB<13> p "--$line[13]--\n";
--P--

# Proving that I'm not crazy and the Perl string comparison operator really works.
DB<14> p ("P" eq "P");
1

# Now since we've shown that $line[13] eq P, let's run that Boolean again.
DB<15> p ($line[13] eq "P")

# (Blank means FALSE) Whaaaat?

# Let's manually set $line[13]
DB<16> $line[13]="P"

# Now let's try that comparison again...
DB<17> p ($line[13] eq "P")
1
DB<18>

# Now it works.  Why?
```

I can work around this by prefiltering the input file but bothers me why this doesn't work.  Am I missing something obvious?

---loren---

Comment: I imagine there's something in your input that we're not seeing and that single "P" you think you have in $line[13] is not really just a single "P".

Comment: Post a sample of the file you're working with

Comment: What version of Perl are you using? What populates `@inst_report_file`? I'd love to see `use Devel::Peek; Dump($line[13]);`.

Answer (score 4):

Find out what your string really is using:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($line[13]));
```

---

[ On further review, the guesses below are most likely incorrect. ]

I suspect you have a trailing newline, in which case you want [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

You could also have trailing spaces. `s/\s+\z//` will remove both trailing spaces and a trailing newline.

Comment: `chomp` won't delete a space.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, oops! "or space" was edited in, and I didn't consider the whole sentence. Fixed

Comment: @TLP, Hum, I seem to have have lept to a false conclusion. Checking using Data::Dumper still good, and if that doesn't help it could be a weird scalar and Devel::Peek might give a clue as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the string characters with `ord`?

```
say ord for (split //, $line[13]);
```

If, for example, you have a `\0` in there, it might not show up in a regular print. With the string `P\0`, I get:

```
$ perl -wE '$a="P\0"; say "--$a--"; say ord for (split //, $a);'
--P--
80
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are unprintable characters in the input, it's not clear why your code doesn't work. Having said that, I would still write that statement as:

`next unless $line[13] eq "P";`

or

`next unless $line[13] =~ /^P$/;` (Theoretically this could be faster.)

You will not need to pre-filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $line[13] isn't supposed to be $line[12]?